# Print Half A4 Page With CSS

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a dot matrix printer and printer use continuous paper. Each page is half A4 size. When I change the page size to A5 landscape, the output looks like this:
[image]

Then I change the page size to A4 portrait. When I do this, the printer prints the printout on the first page, but does not stop at the end of the first page and prints the second page blank.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page   - try @page { size: A5 {orientation}; }

Comment: @kopz i already use A5 landscape but printer print A5 portrait? Any idea about this problem?